# How do I replace a method from base class in C#?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a base class named `Broadcaster` that can broadcast any info (byte arrays) using TCP. Now I want to create a class named `ScreenBroadcaster` that is derived from `Broadcaster` and can broadcast screenshots.

But I faced the following problem. Class `Broadcaster` has a method `Broadcast(byte[] data)` that should be replaced in `ScreenBroadcaster` with just `Broadcast()` (it should take the data to broadcast from the screen). I can't figure out how to do it, please help me!

I know about the keyword `override`, but it doesn't allow to change the signature of the method to override, so it doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Yea you cannot change signature of method but you can create new one `Broadcast()` which will call `base.Broadcast(byte[] data)` with data from screen. That way when you use that class you can call `ScreenBroadcaster.Broadcast()` which will automatically take data from screen and broadcast, or `ScreenBroadcaster.Broadcast(byte[] data)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't implement *exactly* what you want. Why? Consider this sample code:

```cs
byte[] data = new byte[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
Broadcaster bcaster = new ScreenBroadcaster();
bcaster.Broadcast(data);
```

It is absolutely correct. Any reference to `Broadcaster` can refer to `ScreenBroadcaster` because it's derived from `Broadcaster`. But `ScreenBroadcaster` (if it's implemented as you want) hasn't got method `Broadcast(byte[])` that is called here. **What should the executing environment (.NET Framework) do?** No idea. So what you want isn't allowed in C#.

But why don't you *leave* method `Broadcast(byte[] data)` in `ScreenBroadcaster`? You may even use it in `Broadcast()` to avoid code duplication, as said in the comments.

```cs
public void Broadcast() {
  byte[] data;
  // Fill "data" with an image from screen
  Broadcast(data);
}
```